# Using mod_pagespeed with native node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, pagespeed, image-compression, image-optimization

I've been looking for a solution to optimize images for better performance.

After trying some solutions (like [sharp](http://sharp.dimens.io) and [imagemin](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin), which resulted in never smaller, sometimes bigger files), I am now looking to experiment with Google's pagespeed. Unfortunately, pagespeed seems to only support Apache and Nginx, which I would not like to add to my stack just for image optimization (also, I would prefer making the optimization once on upload, and not on server request, even if cached).

I will be very grateful for any information that might help me implement this in native node.js, **and** for any other (working!) image optimization recommendations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you only use node for **dynamic** content (e.g: your application server logic).

For **static** content, such as images, stylesheets and others... just serve them with a regular web server like nginx. There you can use ngx_pagespeed.

Comment: So use it like a self hosted CDN?

Comment: Not necessarily self-hosted

Comment: You can also send your node-generated HTML through an nginx proxy with ngx_pagespeed to get some of the other benefits, like cache extension, combining, minification of HTML and inline css & js.

Answer (score 1):

Try npm module [lwip](https://github.com/EyalAr/lwip).

It's a standalone library(re-built when installing) and no runtime dependencies.

I use its [resize](https://github.com/EyalAr/lwip#resize) and [scale](https://github.com/EyalAr/lwip#scale) operations to create thumb images in my [file service project](https://github.com/hankchiutw/simple-fileservice).

Check if this is what you need. :)

Comment: Interesting, but what about optimization?

Comment: Maybe you could combine lwip and imagemin.For example, scale an image with lwip and pipe the out(transfer as a buffer) to imagemin. Check example code in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/hankchiutw/9fb21f2ea14edc2864c6).